# SVG background animation consume a lot of CPU (loading.io)

Tags: svg, cpu-usage

I've use a SVG background generator for animated SVG backgrounds. I've read that stuff like background-position animation is killing the cpu, but the use on translate will get power from gpu.

I don't get why my svg is taking my FF browser from 3% to 28% with this background.
Chrome is fine, it's going up with 1%.
Can't test Safari, so please post if you have a mac.

Background generator: https://loading.io/background/

```html
<!-- CIRCLE SPOTLIGHT SVG - START -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="margin: auto; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); display: block; z-index: 1; position: relative; shape-rendering: auto;" width="2480" height="1440" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" viewBox="0 0 2480 1440">
<g transform="translate(1240,720) scale(1,1) translate(-1240,-720)"><defs>

<radialGradient id="ldbk-r9105pcf9r" r="1" cx="0.46" cy="0.5" fx="0.54" fy="0.5" fr="0">
  <animate attributeName="fy" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="4.761904761904762s" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" values="0.32;0.6799999999999999;0.32" keySplines="0.5 0 0.5 1;0.5 0 0.5 1" calcMode="spline"></animate>
  <animate attributeName="cy" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="7.142857142857143s" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" values="0.6799999999999999;0.32;0.6799999999999999" keySplines="0.5 0 0.5 1;0.5 0 0.5 1" calcMode="spline"></animate>
  <stop stop-color="#cac2ea" offset="0%"></stop>
  <stop stop-color="#7462bb" offset="33%"></stop>
  <stop stop-color="#221b41" offset="66%"></stop>
  <stop stop-color="#6147c6" offset="100%"></stop>
</radialGradient>

</defs>
<g transform="translate(1240 720)">
<circle cx="0" cy="0" r="1433.8758663147937" fill="url(#ldbk-r9105pcf9r)">
<animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" dur="14.285714285714286s" keyTimes="0;1" values="0;360" repeatCount="indefinite"></animateTransform>
</circle>
</g></g>
</svg>

<!-- CIRCLE SPOTLIGHT SVG - END -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about differences between FF and Chrome, but from this blog post you can have a deeper understanding: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/hardware-accelerated-animations/
In particular, with dev tools you can profile and see how much of the gpu is used actually or not.